# cloudbees jenkins xctool cocoapods Pods.xcconfig not found

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods, cloudbees, xctool

I am running jenkins on cloudbees and using reference shell script to install cocoapods before building the project.

The reference script:

```
# Install xctool via homebrew
/usr/local/bin/brew install xctool

# Run xctool + cocoapods
/usr/local/bin/xctool -workspace CBDemo.xcworkspace -scheme CBDemo -sdk iphoneos7.0 clean build
```

(I've only changed the scheme and workspace name to fit my project)

the output is telling exactly this:

```
The file ‚ÄúPods.xcconfig‚Äù couldn‚Äôt be opened because there is no such file. (/scratch/jenkins/workspace/Style/Pods/Pods.xcconfig)
```

When I add the Pods.xcconfig file generated from pod install, the script goes on and finishes with yet another error - missing referenced cocoapods libraries. Obviously.

Questions I ask:

1) does xctool really run pod install somehow?

2) is there any way to run pod install on cloudbees?

3) how can I possibly get those libraries installed before the build?

Answer (score 1):

case closed - it was either my inattention or it all of a sudden started working. Basically you need to run pod install yourself. So adding line

```
pod install
```

worked just fine:)